# Missing icons phonegap 4 ios

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, phonegap-build

Trying to submit my phonegap app on iTunes Connect, got this errors:

[image: iTunes Connect upload error]

Here my config.xml:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/android/icon.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-57@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
</platform>
```

I've already tried to move config xml to /www folder but the same problem occurs.

Can someone help me? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@felipe,
I have working examples for Phonegap Build. You can borrow from here:

https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Splashscreen-Test

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new directory in root (not www) of your project and place there your icons. Config.xml also should be in a root of the project.

For example 
`<icon src="icons/res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />`

You can also upload your icons manually using xcode.